# SSE not working in android by using domain name

Tags: cordova, openhab

I am using this URL from Ajax “https://username%40gmail.com:password@home.myopenhab.org/rest/events?topics=smarthome/"
to get SSE in client side app using Cordova.
its working fine on IOS but its not working on android.
for same URL if I give IP like "http://192.168.0.1/rest/events?topics=smarthome/” its working fine on both IOS and android.

my code goes like this

```
var eventSource = new EventSource(" +“url”+ /rest/events?topics=smarthome/*");   


eventSource.addEventListener(‘message’, function (eventPayload)
{
//not entering here.
}
```