# where is the default browser locted and how do i update that in cordova android application?

Tags: android, cordova

What is the  default browser used by cordova to load the HTML page?? where is that browser located and how do I update that browser if it is using older version??  Server Sent Events not working in cordova android application.
Does cordova on Android uses chrome or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses `WebView`, which is a part of the Android OS. On older Android versions (before 5.0) it is impossible to update it. On never versions it is updated same way as any other app - using google play.

Starting from Android 6.0 there is a way to choose a `WebView` service in developer options, but most part of users are unable to do it by default (because it requires turning on developer options).

Starting from Android 7.0 Google Chrome `WebView` is set as default `WebView` service, so `WebView` is updated together with Google Chrome updates.

Unfortunately, some manufacturers (e.g. Meizu) prefer to *reinvent a wheel*, and embed their own `WebView` service into their firmware. Sometimes it works not the way it should.

Comment: hello  thanks for the reply  I am using android 7.0 but in my developer options webView implementation showing  Chrome Stable, that means it is using latest version ??

Comment: @parameshsurakod, it means that it is using **Installed version of Chrome**. If your chrome is up to date - then it is the latest version

Comment: hello can u please check this link i am facing the same issue. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001770/sse-not-working-in-android-by-using-domain-name] but when i use crosswalk plugin it works fine but i don't want to use crosswalk plugin

Comment: @parameshsurakod it does not relate to current question. If you have **another question** - ask **another question**

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vladyslav Matviienko if u can please reply to the link that I mentioned above.